# Run shell command with variable in filename via Python

Tags: python, shell

I have files with naming convention

```
st009_out.abc1.dat
st009_out.abc2.dat
st009_out.abc3.dat 
..................
..................
```

I am writing Python code where I want to use data from the file to perform a math function and need to extract the second column from the file. I have tried it this way:

```
for k in range(1,10):
    file1=open('st009_out.abc'+str(k)+'.dat','r')
    ...........
    os.system("awk '{print $2}' st009_out.abc${k}.pmf > raj.dat")
```

but this is not working as it is not taking the value of `k` in the shell command.

How do I progress?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
os.system("awk '{print $2}' st009_out.abc"+str(k)+".pmf > raj.dat")
```

Comment: @rajitha: Also, the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function in Python does exactly what `awk` does in this example.

Comment: Thank you.I got it using split function earlier, as i have been trying to use shell command in python and was stuck at this point. thank you once again for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

You use the filename twice so set it only once

```
for k in range(1,10):
    name = 'st009_out.abc'+str(k)+'.dat'
    file1=open(name,'r')
    ...........
    os.system("awk '{print $2}' " + name  + " > raj.dat")
```

or better rewrite the awk in python